# morris.js - only supports dates on x axis?

Tags: jquery, morris.js

I would like an X axis and Y axis, both of type decimal.

It seems the plugin is entirely focused on the idea the X axis is a date?

I don't have evenly spread data points, so I can't fake it with string labels.

I need it to draw the point at any given X/Y coordinate.

It seems no documentation mentions how to do it... ALL examples are date based.

Maybe it should be called timeseries.js instead.

Can anyone please offer any input (other than changing plugins)?

Thanks G

Answer (score 0):

You can set the option `parseTime` to **false**;

Comment: Thanks for this but it still forces equally spread data points even if it displays labels in non date form

Comment: Well, I am not sure to understand what kind of display you want. Could you please upload a picture of a mock-up or from another chart library that meet with your requirements ?